# Selecting values from one two table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database, one table contains all the users of lets say a social network and the second table contains who follows who. Now when user A searches for user B, I want to be able to not just return user B but also tell if user A is following user B. I tried This but it doesn't work.

```
"SELECT
`destination_id` 
FROM `followers` 
WHERE `source_id` IN
(SELECT `username`
 FROM `userinfo` WHERE `username`
 LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%' OR 
`email`LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%')"
```

Examples of each table
userinfo-->

```
           ID    username    email

           1     ABC        ABC@gmail.com

           2     XYZ        XYZ@live.com
```

followers-->

```
           source_id  destination_id

           ABC        XYZ

           HIJ        JKL
```

And please does this mean i do two seperate queries or can i have both queries as one. Like the above.

Note: `$data` is key values from the user as he inputs the user he searches for and it works. The destination_id and source_id belongs to the followers table and it works like this source_id follows destination_id (i.e. user A follows user B).

Hope its clear.

Comment: Is `userinfo.username` the same data type as `followers.source_id`?

Comment: Can you show 4 or 5 lines of each tables to make it more readable ?

Comment: yes they are of the same data types @PeterGluck and i have made it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  u1.*,
  CASE WHEN u2.username IS NULL THEN 'Not following'
       ELSE 'Following' END is_following
FROM
  userinfo u1 LEFT JOIN followers f
  ON u1.username = f.source_id
  LEFT JOIN userinfo u2
  ON f.destination_id = u2.username
     AND (u2.username LIKE '%B%' OR u2.email LIKE '%B%')
WHERE
  u1.username='A'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/445df/2).

Comment: Please explain what the u1, u2 and f are. this codes are kinda too advanced for me. Thanks.

Comment: Never Mind I understand the codes. works like a charm. Thanks a million

Comment: but please I have a question. In the case where XYZ is a new user and is not in the followers table, it returns null how do I return XYZ even if its not in the followers table but in the userinfo table. i.e. it should return values XYZ following if XYZ is followed by ABC and still return XYZ not folllowing even if it not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT userinfo.username, ifNULL(concat(followers.destination_id, ' IS FOLLOWED'), 'NOT FOLLOWED')
FROM userinfo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN followers
on userinfo.username = followers.destination_id
and followers.source_id = 'ABC'
WHERE (username
 LIKE '%XYZ' OR email LIKE '%XYZ%')
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get your code. how those this code indicate if user A is already following user B

Comment: I think I misunderstood original question, modified query for checking if ABC is following XYZ

Comment: It returns values but the is followed or not followed is not attached to the values returned can you kindly help with that